# Loop and execute code sequentially

Tags: rxjs, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I had to create the code to insert rows in batches of 1K rows, however as the Bookshelf / Knex library runs the code using Promises, I'm having some errors and I need that this loop runs sequentially (only after finishing the first SQL, the second should start).

How can I do this with Promises (or Rx)?

```js
for (var x = 0; x < parser.getCount(); x++) {
    let row = parser.getRow(x);
    if (_.isEmpty(row) || _.isEmpty(row.ch) || _.isEmpty(row.location)) {
        break;
    }

    let locationData = breakDownLocation(row.location);

    middleSql += `(TRIM('${row.ch}'), TRIM('${row.color}'),TRIM('${moment(row.lastUpdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY - HH:mm').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')}'), TRIM('${row.mvsDescription}'), ${locationData.position === '' || _.isUndefined(locationData.position) ? 'NULL' : locationData.position}, TRIM('${locationData.row}'), TRIM('${locationData.sector}'), ${convertStatusToInt(row.status)}, ${locationData.yardId}),`;
    itemsToInsert++;

    if (itemsToInsert >= 1000) {
        let sql = `${beginSql} ${middleSql.substring(0, middleSql.length - 1)} ${endSql}`;
        bookshelf.knex.raw(sql).then(r => {
            //console.log(r);
        })
        .catch(error => { 
            console.error(error);
        });

        middleSql = '';
        itemsToInsert = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use async await, if that is available for you. Make the function where this code resides async and then simply await your sql call. ```await bookshelf.knex.raw(sql);```. You can wrap it in a try catch block to have an error handler per sql call.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite you code using Rx

```js
Observable.of(parser.getCount())
  .concatMap(i => {
    const row = parser.getRow(i);
    if (_.isEmpty(row) || _.isEmpty(row.ch) || _.isEmpty(row.location)) {
      return Observable.empty();
    }

    const locationData = breakDownLocation(row.location);
    return Observable.of(`(TRIM('${row.ch}'), TRIM('${row.color}'),TRIM('${moment(row.lastUpdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY - HH:mm').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')}'), TRIM('${row.mvsDescription}'), ${locationData.position === '' || _.isUndefined(locationData.position) ? 'NULL' : locationData.position}, TRIM('${locationData.row}'), TRIM('${locationData.sector}'), ${convertStatusToInt(row.status)}, ${locationData.yardId}),`);
  })
  .bufferCount(1000)
  .concatMap(commands => {
    const middleSql = commands.join('');
    const sql = `${beginSql} ${middleSql.substring(0, middleSql.length - 1)} ${endSql}`;
    return bookshelf.knex.raw(sql);
  });
```

In above example no error handling is provided if your `bookshelf.knex.raw` errors on a batch, causing all further processing to halt. Depending on what you want you can swallow the error or append retry logic.

If you are able to use `await` that would also be a valid option to keep the code simpler to read because using Rx moves the procedural (for..each) flow into more FP.

Answer (score 0):

I have used `Array.prototype.reduce` to accomplish this type of thing before. It looks something like this.

```
const allDonePromise = someArray.reduce((previous, current) => {
  return previous.then(() => {
    return current.do()
  })
}, Promise.resolve())
```

I concur that using await could help you do it in a more readable way.

Another option would be to use recursion and pass a previous promise back around. Something like.

```
...
const doInserts = function(i = 0, promise = Promise.resolve()) {
  return promise.then(() => {
    ...
    if (itemsToInsert >= 1000) {
      ...
      return doInserts(i + 1, newSavesPromise)
    } else {
      return doInserts(i + 1, promise)
    }
  })
}
```